# Facebook Open Graph : Associate Website with Facebook Page

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I want to make relationship between my Facebook Page & my website.

I have already set up both of them, adding the OG tags to the website. However, it seems there  is no connection between the Facebook Page & my website. The `fb:admin` tag is set to my Facebook user ID, but I want to associate with my Facebook Page instead.

Is it possible ? Is there any Open Graph tags I missed out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible. As seen in the [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) provided by Facebook:

"May 2, 2012 - We will remove the ability to claim domains with a Page ID. The recommended option for claiming domains is with an App ID or User ID and existing domains that have been claimed will continue to work fine."

Comment: So , I can use App ID in `fb:admins` ? I thought I can only use FBID

Comment: No, you can use `fb:admins` with UIDs or you can use `fb:app_id` with an App ID. See the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#ogtags