# Associate Facebook Page likes with website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a Facebook page with 50K+ likes on it and a separate website, when analysed with Moz, that only has a few hundred likes (which I believe are coming from WordPress on the site's blog).

For a number of reasons, I would like to associate the two with each other, so is it possible to link my FB page likes to website?

At this stage I **don't** want a FB Like/Share/Recommend, and simply just want my Facebook page and its like to be representative of my website. I can understand why this might not be possible, but I just thought I would ask.

If it it's not possible (like this post [Facebook Open Graph : Associate Website with Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783485/facebook-open-graph-associate-website-with-facebook-page) indicates) to do with Facebook page's pageId, is there way I can associate a FB app (in the form of a website) with my existing facebook page without having to make a new FB page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to combine/link Likes of an external Website with the Likes/Fans of a Facebook Page.

About associating an App with a Page: You can install an App on a Page, it is called "Page Tab" or "Page App". Of course you don't need to create a new Page for that, you can install an App on every Page you own. You can also use that exact same App for something else on your external website. Check out the "platforms" in the App settings.